# Google Gantt Chart using php, mysqli data as values

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I was asked to do an automated gantt chart. Upon searching, I found this on Google Developer. [Google Gantt Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart)

So, I tried to combine Google Gantt Chart with MySQLi as datasource. Here's my actual code:

```
`<?php

$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_NAME = 'db_gantt';
$DB_USER = 'root';
$DB_PASS = '';


/* Establish the database connection */
$mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

/* select all the weekly tasks from the table */
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT name,complete FROM task_history');


$rows = array();
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(

array('label' => 'Task Name', 'type' => 'string'),
array('label' => 'Percentage', 'type' => 'number')

);
/* Extract the information from $result */
foreach($result as $r) {

  $temp = array();

  $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['name']); 

  // Values

  $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['complete']); 
  $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;

// convert data into JSON format
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
//echo $jsonTable;


?>


<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"> 
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
vardata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', '<?php $jsonTable['name']; ?>');
    data.addRows([
     ['Percentage', '<?php $jsonTable['complete']; ?>',
      null, newDate(2015, 0, 6), daysToMilliseconds(1), 100, 'Duration']
    ]);

    var chart = new 
google.visualization.Gantt(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
</script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--this is the div that will hold the chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>`
```

But nothing is displaying. All I get from this is a white blank page. I am running it using `XAMPP` any ideas on how to make this thing work?
Can you guys help me troubleshoot this one? Thanks. I'm a newbie, by the way. So please be kind.

Comment: "White blank page", aka the White Screen Of Death, usually results from a syntax error or exceeding some resource limit (too much RAM, too much recursion, or too much execution time). Lint your code (eg `php -l`) and check your logs (eg `php -i | grep error_log`).

Comment: try to add ini_set('display_errors', true); on the top most part of this code to see if any errors happened.

Comment: I did what you've said by adding `error log` or `ini_set display error` at the topmost part of my code, but it still remains blank. Now I dunno what's happenin. Is it something to do with the computer am using like @bishop said?